# How to stop NAN appearing in DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am using an api to extract a json file/python dict. When I try to bring it to a pandas data frame I am running into problems

I am using the python request library to get a dict from the address using the `requests.get().text` nested in a `json.loads()` method.

I have tried the following:

```py
#Request_data
jsonfile = json.loads(requests.get(address).text)
```

## Method1

```
df=json_normalize(jsonfile,record_path='history',meta['open','close','high','low','volume'],errors='ignore')
```

## Method2

```
df=json_normalize(jsonfile,meta['open','close','high','low','volume'],errors='ignore')
```

When I try method1 I get a table with dates in a column and open, close, high, low and volume as column headers, however the value in the cell is `NaN`

When I try method2 I get one row and a lot of columns with each date having a open, close, high, low and volume column.

Comment: It’s very hard to help you without the file your working with...

Comment: Thanks @BenPap I attach a snippet of the json:-                                                     ` 'name': 'AAPL', 'history': {'2019-04-26': {'open': '204.90', 'close': '204.30', 'high': '205.00', 'low': '202.12', 'volume': '18649102'}, '2019-04-25': {'open': '206.83', 'close': '205.28', 'high': '207.76', 'low': '205.12', 'volume': '18543206'}, '2019-04-24': {'open': '207.36', 'close': '207.16', 'high': '208.48', 'low': '207.05', 'volume': '17540609'},

`

Comment: So the problem is how your json is formatted. If it was {name: AAPL, history: [{date:2019-04-26, open: 204.90' ect ect}, {date: 2019-04-27, ect ect]} Then method 1 would work. If you want you could use regex to manipulate the json text, then import it with json_normalize.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to understand your data, but I suggest you can create each column by iterate your json data. You can check where the NaN come from in the for-loop.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
col_1, col_2 = [], []

for element in jsonfile:
    col_1.append(element['col_1'])
    col_2.append(element['col_2'])

df['col_1'] = col_1
df['col_2'] = col_2
```

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

@thisray thanks for taking the time to answer. Appreciated. I have come up with this answer and it does the trick, let me know what you think.

```
jsonfile = requests.get(URL)
fin_dict = jsonfile.json()
fin_history_dict = fin_dict['history']
historic_data = list(fin_history_dict.values())
df=pd.DataFrame(data = historic_data,index=fin_dict['history'])
```